# Programmers stack exchange - xml parsing error

Tags: bug, status-declined, firefox

```
XML Parsing Error: unexpected parser state
Location: jar:file:///D:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/chrome/toolkit.jar!/content/global/netError.xhtml
Line Number 329, Column 58:        <div id="ed_netInterrupt">&netInterrupt.longDesc;</div>
---------------------------------------------------------^
```

is this any serious problem?

i got this twice in my firefox browser today. I dont know what is the real probs .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be related to Firefox extensions.

[This bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=569229) on Bugzilla discusses it, but not a fix for it.

However, as far as I can tell, this error is completely random.  My best suggestion is to restart Firefox and see if it works after that.